# multiple forms of same class jquery

Tags: jquery

I got multiple forms that refresh a single div by using some jquery code as shown below. It refers to the class of the form, so that the code is the same for all forms. Problem is, it only takes the input from the last form and sends its to the div, not matter what form is clicked. They should instead send all different information, depending on which form button is clicked.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formlistmenu").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other stuff for a valid form
       $.post('listmenu.php', $(".formlistmenu").serialize(), function(data) {
          $('#select').html(data);
        });
      }
    });
 });


 <form name="myform1" class="formlistmenu" action="" method = "post"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="selectstuff" value ="resources">
 <input type="image" SRC="resources.gif" title="resources">
 </form>

 <form name="myform2" class="formlistmenu" action="" method = "post">
 <input type="hidden" name="selectstuff" value ="items">
 <input type="image" SRC="resources.gif" title="resources">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".formlistmenu").each(function(){
       $(this).validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other stuff for a valid form
       $.post('listmenu.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
          $('#select').html(data);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: it should send either the value items or resources to the div, depending on which picture clicked.

Comment: try replacing `$(this).serialize()` with `$(this).find("input[name='selectstuff']").val()`

Comment: I dont think the hidden stuff is the problem, as it works fine with just one form.

Comment: Maybe I should start over, the validate stuff is not needed anyway. How would you code a simple form to load another php page with posted values into a single div, where there are multiple forms on the same page that call the same page and div, but with other values. (so multiple submit buttons in the way of images)